# Appropriate family to use for continuous response variable (proportion data) with both negative and positive values in glmm?

Tags: r, regression, distributions, mixed-model, glmm

I have a continuous response variable from proportion data with both negative and positive values. Values in response variable range from 0.92 to -0.92. I would like to use glmms but not sure what family to use. As I understand, beta family can be used for proportion data with values between 0 & 1 (both exclusive).

About the experiment, I had a field trial where I observed disease severity on plants, harvested the plants, and distributed the harvested diseased plant pieces into the ground to infect plants in the next year. Next year, I planted healthy plants on the same field and let them infected by infected left-over plant pieces from the previous year. I then subtracted disease severity observed in the current year from disease severity observed in the previous year to find the difference in disease severity. I repeated the same process for 11 years. This is not a time series data. Thank you very much for any assistance.

[image]

[image]

I will be relating this difference to weather variables. Is gaussian family appropriate here? Histogram of residual from running the following doesn't show a normal distribution.

```
mod_1 <-
  glmmTMB(difference ~ perc_temp_days_six + (1|year_ps), family = gaussian(), data = severity_comparison)
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just test for whether the difference in proportions is significantly different than zero?  What is the motivation for a GLMM?

Comment: @jbowman I will be relating these to weather conditions (rainfall, temperature and RH). I have not shown that data here. My response variable will be `difference` and my predictors will be relative humidity, temperature and RH.

Comment: Subtracting your results lost crucial information.  Analyze the results themselves.

Comment: @whuber I have done that separately using beta regression. But now I have been asked to use the difference as response variable.

Comment: "Is gaussian family appropriate here?" only you can tell us this, by executing the standard normality checks on residuals from such a model. But FWIW, this is what I would start with.

Comment: Just because the difference is what you are interested in does not compel you to model it directly.  You could, for instance, model both responses and then compute the differences of your estimates.

Comment: @whuber Is there any example code where it has been done?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=repeated+measures+count+generalized+linear+model produces some helpful posts.

Comment: @JohnMadden I have updated the question with histogram of residuals. It doesn't show normal distribution, so I'm not Gaussian is the right distribution.

Comment: @whuber Thank you.